# pyspark: unexpected behaviour when using multiple UDF functions on the same column (with arrays)

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

Does someone know what's happening when you use multiple udf functions:

I create a test dataframe and two exaple udf functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

mylist = [
    [[1,2,3]],
    [[4,5,6]]
]

def f1(tlist):
    tlist[0]=111
    return 'result f1 is: {}'.format(tlist)
f1_udf = udf(f1, )

def f2(tlist):
    tlist[1]=222
    return 'result f2 is: {}'.format(tlist)
f2_udf = udf(f2, )

df = spark().createDataFrame(mylist).toDF('arr')
df.show()
```

Giving following result:

```
+---------+
|      arr|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|
+---------+
```

then, I apply each function separately:

```
df.withColumn('f1', f1_udf('arr')).show(10, False)
```

gives

```
+---------+-------------------------+
|arr      |f1                       |
+---------+-------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|result f1 is: [111, 2, 3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|result f1 is: [111, 5, 6]|
+---------+-------------------------+
```

and

```
df.withColumn('f2', f2_udf('arr')).show(10,False)
```

gives

```
+---------+-------------------------+
|arr      |f2                       |
+---------+-------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|result f2 is: [1, 222, 3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|result f2 is: [4, 222, 6]|
+---------+-------------------------+
```

**But, and here starts the unexpected behaviour**

```
(df
 .withColumn('f1', f1_udf('arr'))
 .withColumn('f2', f2_udf('arr'))
).show(10, False)
```

**gives and unexpected result, mixing the result of both functions in the second function call**

```
+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
|arr      |f1                       |f2                         |
+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|result f1 is: [111, 2, 3]|result f2 is: [111, 222, 3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|result f1 is: [111, 5, 6]|result f2 is: [111, 222, 6]|
+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
                                                    ^^^ : unexpected result
```

**And when changing the order of calling the functions,**

```
(df
 .withColumn('f2', f2_udf('arr'))
 .withColumn('f1', f1_udf('arr'))
).show(10, False)
```

**gives a different, also unexpected result:**

```
+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
|arr      |f2                       |f1                         |
+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|result f2 is: [1, 222, 3]|result f1 is: [111, 222, 3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|result f2 is: [4, 222, 6]|result f1 is: [111, 222, 6]|
+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
                                                         ^^^ : different unexpected result
```

It seems that calling the functions on a fixed, not changed spark column, are not independent from each other, meaning that if we call both functions (even with lots of other code inbetween) mixes the results of the first function call in the next...
Or, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Spark passes the same array into both functions `f1` and `f2`. As the first function changes the content of the array, the second function also sees these changes. You can see that if you add the line

```python
print("f1: id  of array is {}, content is {}".format(id(tlist), tlist))
```

to the first function and

```python
print("f2: id  of array is {}, content is {}".format(id(tlist), tlist))
```

to the second function.

This prints

```
f1: id  of array is 139782923179912, content is [1, 2, 3]
f2: id  of array is 139782923179912, content is [111, 2, 3]
f1: id  of array is 139782923180040, content is [4, 5, 6]
f2: id  of array is 139782923180040, content is [111, 5, 6]
```

(maybe printed slightly out of order)

So the second function sees the array that has been changed in the first function.

To solve the problem, the functions should create their own copies of the array and change only these copies:

```python
def f1(tlist):
    print("f1: id  of array is {}, content is {}".format(id(tlist), tlist))
    newlist = tlist.copy()
    newlist[0]=111
    return 'result f1 is: {}'.format(newlist)
```

For `f2` accordingly.

Another way to get the expected behaviour is to declare boths udfs as [non-deterministic](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedFunction.html#asNondeterministic--):

```python
f1_udf = F.udf(f1, ).asNondeterministic()
f2_udf = F.udf(f2, ).asNondeterministic()
```

However, I cannot explain why this helps.